# Rails: Trouble with has many through relationships

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, relational-database

I've been having a bit of difficulty understanding the whole has many through concept and how it works in Rails, I presume it does the leg work for you, as I'm used to building the associations manually. I currently have a Billing System, and I'm trying to create an orders section, and obviously my order must have many products, so I've normalised the database to 3rd normal form, so that the Orders and the Products are linked via another table named ordered products, this table contains the ID of the order and the ID of the Product, along with the Quantity of product ordered. I have created the models based on what I know of has_Many :through in Rails via the Code School tutorial, however I've copied it exactly how they had it, but there must be some sort of difference between mines and their's. This is the model files that I currently have:

Order Model:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :ClientID, :OrderTotal
  has_many :orderedproducts
  has_many :products, through: :orderedproducts, :source => :product

end
```

Ordered Product Model:

```
class Orderedproduct < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :OrderID, :ProductID, :QuantityOrdered
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :product
end
```

Products Model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    #This line makes these elements accessible outside of the class.
    attr_accessible :ProductName, :ProductPrice, :ProductQuantity, :ProductSupplier

    has_many :orderedproducts
    has_many :orders, through: :orderedproducts, :source => :order

    #These attributes ensure that the data entered for each element is valid and present.
    validates_presence_of :ProductName
    validates_presence_of :ProductPrice
    validates_numericality_of :ProductPrice
    validates_presence_of :ProductQuantity
    validates_numericality_of :ProductQuantity
    validates_presence_of :ProductSupplier

end
```

I added the source attribute as I was getting an error in the console suggesting that I should add the source attribute to the has_many :through line. This is the error that I receive in the console when I try to add a product to an order:

```
irb(main):017:0> order.products = Product.find(4)
  Product Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `products`.* FROM `products` WHERE `products`.`id` = 4 LIMIT 1
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the source association(s) :ProductID in model Orderedproduct. Try 'has_many :products, :through => :orderedproducts, :source => <name>'. Is it one of :order or :product?
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:509:in `check_validity!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:26:in `initialize'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:24:in `initialize'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_through_association.rb:10:in `initialize'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/associations.rb:160:in `new'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/associations.rb:160:in `association'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:51:in `block in define_writers'
        from (irb):17
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it's the product= method; order doesn't have a 'product', it has many 'products'.

You can:

```
order.products << some_product
```

The CamelCase is, unfortunately, also a problem. The associations from Order and Product, will look for an order_id or product_id, respectively, and won't find them. Solutions would be changing the column names to snake_case, or adding a :foreign_key => ... option.

Answer (score 0):

Because Order has_many Products, you get a #products method from Rails, not a #product method.

What you can do is use your Order instance to create a related OrderedProducts, and add the Product to that instance.

```
order = Order.new
ordered_product = order.ordered_products.build
ordered_product.product = Product.find(4)
```

The problem with the #product method on Order is that there is meant to be a collection, so how is your code to know which one you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong array operator, should have been the << operator rather than the = operator, as I was adding an element into the array.